# Django 1.11 template inheritance {% extends 'base.html' %} display error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.11, django-inheritance

Beforehand, thanks to everyone who could help. I'm having some strange behavior of the Django "template inheritance" - the main problem is {% extends 'base.html' %} in (menu.html) displays nothing in the target (base.html) document. And on the contrary - Django takes the header from base.html and loads it in the (menu.html), that is rather strange, taking into account the logic of inheritance.

I've read all the similar questions, tried different approaches, but nothing... Anyway - the "include" tag works perfectly with all the templates.

I'm having the Django 1.11.11 with python 3.6.4 on windows 10.

Let me list the documents itself:

**menu.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
     Some text
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body> 
    {% block title %}
    {% endblock %}
</body> 

</html>
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from linguistic import views
from linguistic.views import index, menu, about, contact

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^menu/$', views.menu),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):    
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'foo':'bar'})    

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')  

def contact(request):    
    return render(request, 'contact.html')  

def menu(request):    
    return render(request, 'menu.html', {'foo':'bar'})
```

**Settings.py** elements

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

ROOT_URLCONF = 'linguistic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**The project directory structure:**

```
Django_111:

--Include
--Lib
--linguistic
-----setting.py
-----urls.py
-----views.py
--Scripts
--tcl
--templates
-----base.html
-----about.html
-----menu.html
-----contact.html
--manage.py
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are seeing and what you expect to see. If you go to `localhost:8000/menu/`, the view will render the `menu.html` template. That will take the `base.html` (the template it is extending) and substitute the `{% title %}` block from `menu.html`. So the rendered template will contain `<body>Some text</body>`. Is that the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: After body you must have block to `{% block content %} `
`{{ content }}` `{% endblock %}` is missing, yes agree with @Alasdair

Comment: Alasdair, hi. I expect this behavior, but the content inherited from menu.html is not displayed. So the localhost:8000 (with base.html as index) displays nothing. Tried also to rewrite the paths with absolute directories, t didn't help either. 
Anup, tried with the {{ content }} - with brackets inside the block, but nothing displays also.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting index to display though, you don't have anything which uses foo in base.html. Why would you expect it to inherit from menu? That only happens in the menu view. (Please ignore Anup's comment about {{ content }}, it is a complete red herring.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, {'foo':'bar'} i've just added to test the environment and that substitution is working, it is, i've just forgot to delete this piece. Anyway it doesn't affect the inheritance behavior. I expect to see - that base.html will load {% block title %} Some text {% endblock %} from menu.html, but it doesn't'.

Comment: But why would you expect that? The index view does not render menu.html, only the menu view does that. If you go to /, you will only see whatever is in base.html. To see whatever is in menu.html, you need to go to the view that renders it, which is /menu/.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, you're definitely right. But i mean that the template inheritance with {% extends 'base.html' %} doesn't work: base.html doesn't load the block {% block title %} from menu.html, but should.

Comment: But you said to Alasdair that you *do* see the content of menu.html when you go to localhost:8000/menu/. So do you, or don't you?

Comment: )) localhost:8000/menu/ - this works fine. I mean that going to localhost:8000 - base.html doesn't display the block inherited from "menu.html". Sorry, if i mixed the things )

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too.
The solution is to write *"parent folder"* of *"child html"* like:

```
{% extends [parent_folder] / [child.html] %}
```

In your case, you want to extend *"menu.html"* from *"base.html"* as I understood from your question. 
 
So in the first line of *"menu.html"* write:

```
{% extends 'templates/base.html' %}
```

I do not get why it is works so in Django 1.11, but the solution is above :)